# How to avoid jQuery UI Tooltip getting cut off by viewport, while keeping arrow on tooltip trigger?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm trying to position a tooltip on an element, so that the tooltip is not cut off by the left/right viewports. Currently, it flips if cut off from the top or bottom viewports, which is fine. I tried to add `collision: "fit flip"` as a tooltip option, but that screws up the arrow's position. You can view my attempt here: http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/yJAKYq

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried a few things, and it doesn't look like the underlying code for your arrow allows you to specify anything but in the center.  If you want to do "exploratory surgery", then set the `hide` option to, say, 120000.  That will leave the tooltip open for two minutes.  That will let you inspect the tooltip and look at the underlying CSS.  I found that the arrow has a class called .arrow applied to it, for example.  You might find a CSS value you can change in the right circumstances (for example, set to "flipfit", and if center of tooltip != center of button then you're in a fit situation).

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark here...

Any chance you can just adding additional padding to the left?

```
main {
  padding-left: 200px
}
```